# Machine state in a etcd cluster

Tags: etcd, raft

Is there an easy way to figure out who is the current leader in an etcd cluster (except for searching through the logs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/stats/self
```

yields

```
{
"leaderInfo": {
    "leader": "10.132.90.172",
    "startTime": "2015-04-16T11:57:49.568452941Z",
    "uptime": "1h18m25.433506066s"
},
"name": "10.132.90.172",
"recvAppendRequestCnt": 0,
"sendAppendRequestCnt": 0,
"startTime": "2015-04-16T11:57:49.56843843Z",
"state": ""
}
```